# Modification of Non-relativistic Schrodinger Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Why the non-relativistic schrodinger equation should be modified to address Bosons and Fermions ?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be. Bosons and fermions each exhibit different exchange properties implying that the wave functions must be either symmetric in the case of bosons or anti symmetric in the case of fermions.

For fermions the anti-symmetry of the wave function means that under particle exchange we have:

$$\psi(x_1,x_2,x_3)=-\psi(x_2,x_1,x_3)=\psi(x_2,x_3,x_1)=\ldots$$

E.g. exchanging any two particles rotates the global phase by $(2n+1)\pi$

For bosons the symmetry of the wave function means that under particle exchange we have:

$$\psi(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\psi(x_2,x_1,x_3)=\psi(x_2,x_3,x_1)=\ldots$$

E.g. exchanging any two particles rotates the global phase by $(2n)\pi$

If you initialize with a symmetric/anti-symmetric wavefunction and evolve it in time, it will remain symmetric/anti-symmetric. As such you do not need to modify the Schroedinger equation to deal with bosons/fermions you just need to modify your initial conditions.

Comment: This is true only if the non-relativistic Hamiltonian preserves the symmetry, and in general it doesn't (you can easily think of potentials which have no definite symmetry when exchanging two variables).

Comment: Schroedinger equation is generically for structureless particles: spinless bosons. For spin degenerate systems this does not matter, but for spin $1/2$ particles, the Pauli equation is more appropriate. Your answer only addresses the symmetry in the wave function for many-particle states, not how you obtain the wave function.